# How to remove "missing script files" warnings in add-on prefs?

Tags: add-on

### Background

I have an issue periodically with my add-ons staying around somehow. This mostly happens on add-ons that I work on (occasionally when I keep reloading them), but also on others such as the pie menus add-on.

### Problems

- "missing script files" warning in user prefs
- add-on path cannot be found so I can't see where to remove anything from...(i.e., I receive this warning when I try to run `bpy.ops.wm.addon_remove(module='ui_pie_menus_official')` from the python console window)
- the *modules* stay around on some add-ons after I remove them

### Question

How can I remove these modules so they will stop giving me these warnings?

[image]

Comment: You've probably script-cadavers in your Blender python enviroment (like me, unfortunately :() What can be done is find out the Name of the Addon-Scriptfiles, search for them in your Blender Python folders and delete them.

Comment: By blender python folders you mean in the *Blender/2.78/scripts/addons/* folder?

Comment: (In Windows 7) there is an an additional Folder
"C:\Users\...\Application Data\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.77\scripts\addons"
The Script Location is probably there.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in Blender 2.83.
I suggest that you load the Blender Add-on factory settings by going to the "Edit" menu, Select the "gear" icon to get to "Preferences..." and after that, click on the lower left corner button besides "Save Preferences*" (it shows 3 horizontal lines through it).
Then, by re-enabling the Add-ons one by one, you'll easily spot the culprit for the missing scripts.
Usually, an updated version might have been already published if you do a search for the defective Add-on.

In the case of the Blenderkit being the one giving you problems, go to this answer provided by SHA:
https://blenderartists.org/t/blender-2-8-blender-kit-addon-install-error/1173445/12?u=pierregagne98

Hope that helps!

[image: BLENDER PREFERENCES BUTTON]

[image: LOAD FACTORY PREFERENCES OPTION]

[image: Before activation of defective Add-On]

[image: Error Message after clicking activation check mark's box]